Why a PHP Class Code Won't Run on Live Server
namespace Controller; 

defined('ROOTPATH') OR exit('Access Denied!');
class IT
{
    use MainController;

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = "IT";

        $this->view('it', $data);
    }
}

This is my IT.php controller, and I have an it.view.php view file.
It runs well as such in the localhost server of my PC. When I uploaded the website to Hostinger, however, it was displaying a page-not-found message, while the rest of website pages displayed properly. I had to change the class name to It to make it work.
Any idea of why it runs on the localserver but not on Hostinger's server?
I tried class IT, which did not work. Then class It, which worked.

Is your local dev server a Windows machine? Then it is probably an issue with a case-insensitive Windows file system, vs. a Linux one that is case sensitive. Likely a problem at the stage where the autoloading mechanism tries to load the class file (not sure why that would result in a "page-not-found message" though, but we don't know the details of your system.)

Yes, my machine is Windows.

Also run composer dump-autoload

It runs well now. My question is about what could be the technical issues that make the code workable locally but won't do so live.
